# Android Studio emulator installing

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have downloaded the marshmallow x86_64 zip file from [the following link](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-23_r19.zip) by using my browser.

How to install this or where to extract this?

I am using Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Studio installed, you should have the Android SDK Manager. You download system images using that, so you should not need to go find the actual links to the images yourselves, but you should extract that to the SDK location, which again, if you have that folder, you have the SDK Manager application

Comment: by download using Android SDK Manager takes long time and failed atlast... due to this I use this way

Comment: It downloads the same link if you have not used a proxy, as far as I know

Comment: @suhail mc Even if you use proxy set that via preferences->system settings->http proxy.  Because you may need to download dependencies or something again via gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the folder to 
Android SDK -> system-images -> android-23 -> google_apis

Or if you want to paste the folder data
Android SDK -> system-images -> android-23 -> google_apis -> x86_64